# <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>. getting this errors after adding mapbox_gl and its sdk

Tags: java, android, gradle, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android

app\buid.gradle

```
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin : 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    namespace "com.example.movini_app"
    compileSdkVersion 33
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.movini_app"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.3.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.maps:android:10.12.1'
}
```

android/build.gradle

```
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            credentials {
                // Do not change the username below.
                // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
                username = "mapbox"
                // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
                password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN'] ?: ""
            }
        }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> and those are the kind of errors am getting
> Note: C:\Users\Eya\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\cloud_firestore-4.5.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestoreMessageCodec.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngine found in modules jetified-common-23.4.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.4.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineCallback found in modules jetified-common-23.4.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.4.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineProvider found in modules jetified-common-23.4.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.4.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineRequest found in modules jetified-common-23.4.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.4.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineRequest$1 found in modules jetified-common-23.4.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.4.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineRequest$Builder found in modules jetified-common-23.4.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.4.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineResult found in modules jetified-common-23.4.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.4.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsListener found in modules jetified-common-23.4.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.4.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsManager found in modules jetified-common-23.4.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.4.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsManager$AccuracyAuthorization found in modules jetified-common-23.4.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.4.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)

```
 Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
```

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Answer (score 5):

Go to `android>app>build.gradle`.
Under dependencies section add this line
`implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))`.
That's how I fixed my problem, hopefully it works for you as well.

```
dependencies {
    implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))
}
```

Then make sure to run your android studio or vs code  as an administrator once.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution which was just related to `multiDexing`.

Just go to your app module `build.gradle` and add

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21 
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        multiDexEnabled true <-- add this line
    }
    ...
}
```

And to the dependencies section:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1" <-- add this line too
}
```

This is the link to the docs: https://developer.android.com/build/multidex#groovy